# Segmentation Fault in BFS sequential algorithm

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've made a parallel version of the BFS algortihm, now I'm trying to serialize the same algrithm to get an idea of the speed-up.
My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Node 
{
    int begin;     // begining of the substring
    int num;    // size of the sub-string 
};

void BFS (Node *Va, int *Ea, bool* Fa, bool *Xa, int *Ca,bool *para, int tid)
{

    int nid;

        if (Fa[tid] == true && Xa[tid] == false)
        {
          Fa[tid] = false; 

                   for (int i = Va[tid].begin;  i < (Va[tid].begin + Va[tid].num); i++) // Va begin is where it's edges' subarray begins, Va is it's                                                                        number of elements
            {           
                nid = Ea[i];

                if (Xa[nid] == false)
                {
                  Ca[nid] = Ca[tid] + 1;
                  Fa[nid] = true;
                  *para = true;
                }   
            }
            Xa[tid] = true;
        }

}

int main()
{


    struct Node Va[4]; 
    Va[0].begin=0; 
    Va[0].num=2; 
    Va[1].begin=1; 
    Va[1].num=0; 
    Va[2].begin=2; 
    Va[2].num=2; 
    Va[3].begin=1; 
    Va[3].num=0; 
    int edges[]={1,2,3,1}; 
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&Va,sizeof(Node)*4); 
    //cudaMemcpy(Va,node,sizeof(Node)*4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    int Ea[4]={1,2,3,3}; 
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&Ea,sizeof(Node)*4); 
    //cudaMemcpy(Ea,edges,sizeof(Node)*4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    bool Fa[4]={false};     
    int source=0; 
    Fa[source]=true; 
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&Fa,sizeof(bool)*4); 
    //cudaMemcpy(Fa,frontier,sizeof(bool)*4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    bool Xa[4]={false}; 
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&Xa,sizeof(bool)*4); 
    //cudaMemcpy(Xa,visited,sizeof(bool)*4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    int Ca[4]={0}; 
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&Ca,sizeof(int)*4); 
    //cudaMemcpy(Ca,custo,sizeof(int)*4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    //dim3 grid(1,1,1); 
    //dim3 threads(4,1,1); 


    bool* para; 
    int i=1,n=0,j;


    for (j=0; j<4 ; j++)
    {
    BFS(Va,Ea,Fa,Xa,Ca,para,j);

    printf("Run number: %d >> ",n); 
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
        printf("%d  ",Ca[i]); 
    printf("\n");


    printf ("\n             Xa :"); 
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
        printf("%d  ",Xa[i]); 
    printf("\n\n");



    n++;
    printf("%d",n);
    }



        printf("\nFinal:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
        printf("%d  ",Ca[i]); 
    printf("\n");

}
```

Note that it's a former a CUDA program...

Also, I'm compiling with g++ so I can use bool variables.

The problem is: I'm getting a seg fault as soon as I lunch the first run of the BFS function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`para` is not pointing to anything, yet you assign to it.

declare it as `bool para` and pass `&para` instead